# Comprehension to find the min in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am curious about a thing:

I have a dict, for example with a car as key and a value regarding its speed. Now, I want to find the key with the lowest value.

```
car_dict = {'mercedes': 200, 'fiat': 100, 'porsche': 300, 'rocketcar': 600}
```

I know this code works with O(1)

```
car_value = list(car_dict.values())
car_key = list(car_dict.keys())
min_stats = min(car_value)
print(car_key[car_value.index(min_stats)])
```

and this one too with O(n)

```
keys = []
values = []
for name, value in car_dict.items():
    keys.append(name)
    values.append(value)

min_value = min(values)
print(keys[values.index(min_value)])
```

I am currently trying to better understand comprehensions, therefore, my question is if there would be a possible approach to this problem with list comprehensions.

I was thinking about something like this

```
worst = {name for name, stats in car_dict if min(stats)}
```

However, I guess that I still misunderstand something in the `if` part.

BTW correct me if I am wrong with my belief in the Big O complexity above.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are incorrect with `I know this code works with O(1)`. `list(car_dict.values())` requires iteration over all values and is therefore O(n).

Comment: Does the first block really work in `O(1)`?

Comment: Thanks! @jpp  did'nt know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know this code works with O(1):
>
> `car_value = list(car_dict.values())`

This is incorrect. To form a list from a view you must iterate over all values. This operation will have time complexity of O(n).

In general, creating a list of keys and values is not necessary. Avoid these operations as they are expensive.

Note that `min` can work directly on `dict.items`, which is a view of key-value pairs. This is only advisable if you only have a single car with the minimum value:

```
car, value = min(car_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])  # (fiat, 100)
```

Since dictionaries are not considered ordered (unless you are using Python 3.7), for duplicate minima the result will not be certain. In this case, you can calculate the minimum value and then use a list comprehension:

```
min_val = min(car_dict.values())
min_cars = [car for car, value in car_dict.items() if value == min_val]  # ['fiat']
```

You can also use `next` with a generator expression to extract the first such car:

```
min_car_first = next(car for car, value in car_dict.items() if value == min_val)
```

Of course, in the case of a single car with the minimum value, this will give the same result as the first solution `min(car_dict.items(), ...)`.

Comment: Thank you @jpp!! really comprehensive!

Answer (score 0):

This would do you can compare the key's value to the min of the values

```
worst = [i for i in car_dict if car_dict[i] == min(car_dict.values())]
```

Comment: You need to replace `d` by `car_dict `

Comment: @Bazingaa I use d in my vim, copied over as that , replaced

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Thank you!

Comment: @Bazingaa hahahah wow nice catch, I always forget to convert back to OP naming system I like short variable names, I know you had to have the same answer, you are usually have something very similar to mysefl

Comment: @vash_the_stampede: That's why I didn't post. I am a fan of list comprehensions ;)

Comment: @Bazingaa same, I live for these problems, but man this morning some of the questions, not this one, were off the wall, I was like what the heck is going on right now, just non-sense questions across the board, this one was nice

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this problem in faster than linear time, but you can solve it in linear time **in one pass**:

```
min_speed = None
that_car = None
for car,speed in car_dict.items():
    if min_speed is None or speed < min_speed:
        that_car, min_speed = car, speed
that_car
#'fiat'
```

Answer (score 0):

well I'm not sure what is the run time of this one but you can try it it works for me :

```
>>> d = {'mercedes': 200, 'fiat': 100, 'porsche': 300, 'rocketcar': 600}
>>> d.items()
[('mercedes', 200), ('fiat', 100), ('porsche', 300) , ('rocketcar',600)]
>>> # find the minimum by comparing the second element of each tuple
>>> min(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) 
('fiat', 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
car_dict = {'mercedes': 200, 'fiat': 100, 'porsche': 300, 'rocketcar': 600}
min_car = {}
for car in car_dict:
    if not min_car or car_dict[car] < min_car['speed']:
        min_car['name'] = car
        min_car['speed'] = car_dict[car]
print(min_car)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you shouldn't solve this problem with a comprehension because you can't do assignment in a comprehension. Iterating the dictionary you can find the minimum in a single pass:

```
car_iterator = iter(car_dict.items())
slowest_car, min_speed = next(car_list)
for car, speed in car_iterator:
    if speed < min_speed:
        slowest_car = car
```