# Find minimum key value from list of dicts, ignoring None values

Tags: python

Given a List of Dict:

```
myList = [{"id":1, "qty":100},
          {"id":2, "qty":None},
          {"id":3, "qty":-60},
          {"id":4, "qty":120},
          {"id":5}]
```

What is the most succinct way of returning the minimum qty in myList, ignoring None values and missing values (i.e. -60 in this example); or None if no item has a non-None qty value?

My current solution is long-winded:

```
minval = 999999    # Largest feasible value for qty
for item in myList:
    if item.get('qty', None) is not None:
        minval = min(minval, item['qty'])
if minval = 999999:
    minval = None
```

I also don't like the hard-coded 999999 initial value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comprehension to find the min in a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468270/comprehension-to-find-the-min-in-a-dict)

Comment: Do you expect to get `-60` as a result or the object with the minimum quantity?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I'm curious as to why you're using a list of dictionaries for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min` with generator:

```
myList = [{"id": 1, "qty": 100},
          {"id": 2, "qty": None},
          {"id": 3, "qty": -60},
          {"id": 4, "qty": 120}]

print(min(d.get('qty') for d in myList if d.get('qty') is not None))
```

Outputs

```
-60
```

In Python >= 3.8 you can use the walrus operator so `d.get('qty')` is not evaluated twice:

```
print(min(val := d.get('qty') for d in myList if val is not None))
```

If you expect a situation in which all `qty` values will be `None`, you can pass `default=None` (or whatever value you want) to `min`, so it won't complain that it got an empty sequence.

Comment: Thanks. To cover missing keys I guess I should use: ```print(min(d['qty'] for d in myList if d.get(qty, None) is not None))```

Comment: @nakb correct, or just `d.get(qty)` since `None` is the default for `.get`

Comment: what if they are all None (..or None if no item has a non-None qty value?)??

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Then do `print(min((d['qty'] for d in myList if d['qty'] is not None), default=None))` or whatever sentinel value OP deems valid

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the `None`'s out and then get the minimum with a key

```
 min(filter(lambda x: x["qty"] is not None, myList), key=lambda x: x["qty"])
```

This will return the object with the smallest quantity, if you wish to get the integer value you'll need to access that from the dictionary afterwards

Comment: what if they are all `None` (*..or None if no item has a non-None qty value?*)??

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - Different ways the op could handle it, I'd go with catching the exception here if they needed to to avoid iterating over the list before hand (or provide a default which DeepSpace includes in their comment (and I'd forgotten about))

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

x=pd.DataFrame(myList)["qty"].min()
#outputs:
>> -60.0
```

Comment: probably a HUGE overkill if OP is not already using pandas

Answer (score -2):

```
min([max(0,x['qty']) for x in myList if x['qty']])
```